# Importing CSV file into a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, import, csv

I am using Python with pandas to import a CSV file into a table in Postgres

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv('products.csv', sep=';', low_memory=False)
engine = create_engine('postgresql://myuser:mypass@server/postgres')
df.to_sql('new_table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=20000)
```

The .csv file size is ~10GB. I left the script running for 15 hours but it's nowhere near finishing. What better way can I use to push the db to the server?

I can't import the db from the server directly because the compressed file size is larger than the size allowed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm trying to upload a CSV file(table) to a server, on a PostgreSQL db. I will remove the sql-server tag, sorry about that

Comment: Does Python allow you to use `copy ... from stdin`?  That would be much faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would get a memory error then. I can't upload the whole table in one go.

Comment: `copy from stdin` streams the file from the client to the server. It does not load the whole file into memory - at least with `psql` and Java this is the case. I don't know Python though

Comment: can't you just write a sql script to insert them? like COPY table FROM 'path' WITH (FORMAT csv); keep in mind the names of the columns have to match

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if that's the case then I'll try to copy it directly with `psql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you were right, `psql` was the way to go. I will update my answer when I manage to copy the CSV with python the same way as with `psql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `psql` to push the CSV file to the table, as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name.

```
psql -h port -d db -U user -c "\copy products from 'products.csv' with delimiter as ',' csv header;"
```

It only took a couple of minutes to copy the table, compared to 10+ hours with the python script.